# PHP accessing parent

Tags: php, class, inheritance

I'm having trouble accessing a parent's variable like the following:

```
class Priveleges
{
    protected $user_id;

    public __construct($user_id)
    {
         $this->user_id = $user_id;
    }
 }
```

And now my subclass:

```
class userInfo extends Priveleges
{

    public function __construct($user_id)
    {
         parent::__construct($user_id);
    }

    public function showID()
    {
        return $this->user_id;
    }
}


$a = new userInfo(63);
echo $a->showID();
```

The ouput I would expect would be 63 wouldn't it? However, it doesn't output anything...

Comment: And the output you get is...?

Comment: It doesn't output anything...that's the issue

Comment: Do you have `display_errors` turned off? There's a `function` missing, but apart from that, it seems to work. (See answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you instead get "unexpected `__construct`", that would be because you're missing a `function` here:

```
protected $user_id;

public __construct($user_id)
{
     $this->user_id = $user_id;
}
```

After fixing that, [the output is indeed 63](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9RCfHg).

Comment: You're absolutely right... My Priveleges class is a lot more detailed than that and it seems I had accidently removed the function portion to copy and paste elsewhere.... I would have never noticed that. I broke my head for an hour trying to figure out why my child class no longer works!!